# Service Injection works for refresh but not state.go

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-ui-router, angular-services

### Introduction

We had the following at the beginning of our controller that had a missing service from the '$inject' method in comparison with the controller parameters ( `dialogs` was missing).

```
ThematicAreaListController = ($stateParams, $modal, $state, $scope,  $filter, CrudService, Enumerations) ->
 ThematicAreaListController.$inject = ['$stateParams', '$modal', '$state', '$scope', '$filter', 'dialogs', 'CrudService', 'Enumerations']
```

On reload the `CrudService` was properly referable by that name. On state.go (route navigation), the `CrudService` was available as `dialogs`.

We have since added `dialogs` to the params and everything works but don't understand this internal angular behaviour so asking below...

### Question

**Why would `CrudService` be injected as `CrudService` on reload, but as `dialogs` on `$state.go` ?**